# Open CV accessing and setting pixels conditionally

Tags: c++, opencv, colors, pixel, mat

Hello I have an image of text with bounding boxes on the text.  I'm given all coordinates and I want to white or black out anything not in the bounding box (background stuff). So far I have something like this in OpenCV

```
    for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
{   
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; j++)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < coor.size(); k++)
        {   
            if (!((j >= coor[k][0].x) && (j <= coor[k][2].x) && (i >= coor[k][0].y) && (i <= coor[k][1].y)))
            {
                image.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Coor is a vector of vector of points that hold all corner points, and for now I'm checking whether or not a point is in there or not and altering the color. If i remove the NOT from the condition I am able to change pixel colors of whats inside the boxes, If i removed the not, every pixel changes :/.  Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: create a cv::Rect from your bounding box and then image(rect).setTo(0);

Comment: That would work if I wanted to change the contents in the box but I'd like to change the contents outside the box.

Comment: create a mask that covers all excpet the box and use `.setTo(value, mask);`

Comment: e.g. `cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat(image.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255)); cv::rectangle(yourBoxAsRect, cv::Scalar(0), -1);`